# Exception in iOS 8 Today Widget

Tags: objective-c, user-interface, exception, ios8, ios-app-extension

What does the user experience when there is an unhandled exception in an iOS 8 Today Widget?

Does it just reload the widget from scratch? What happens if the exception is continuous?

Is the user forced to manually re-add the widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension may try to reload after a crash, and may continue to do so for a few times. You will see it flashes blank when it does it.

But that will eventually stop, and it will start showing "unable to load".

You will need to remove and add the widget to run it again.